# Moment.js constructor in strict checking mode returns different types in different environments

Tags: momentjs

I'm using a function to format dates that arrive as different types and in different formats, the ultimate goal is to localize and format the result with moment.

To check for different formats in string inputs I try to create a moment object with each supported format and check if it's valid.

```
const DATE_FORMATS = ['DD/MM/YYYY', 'DD-MM-YYYY', 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'YYYY-MM-DD'];

export const dateFormat = (date, format = 'DD/MM/YYY', toBeMultiplied = true) => {
    let formattedDate = date;
    if (typeof (date) === 'string') {
      let found = false;
      for (const date_format of DATE_FORMATS) {
        formattedDate = moment(date, date_format);
        if (formattedDate.isValid()) { found = true; break; }
      }
      if (!found) return 'Invalid date string';
    } else if (typeof (date) === 'number') {
      formattedDate = toBeMultiplied ? date * 1000 : date;
    }

    return moment(formattedDate).format(format);
};
```

For some reason this works in my local environment, but when I release it and try the same thing from the server the moment constructor returns a string.

[image]

What is going on? Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Since posting the original question I realized that this is just a quirk of the debugger, possibly due to the fact that momentjs is a promise based library and with different environments the resolution flow isn't 100% consistent.

Since this is just a hunch I'll leave the question unanswered for now.